# using `growisofs` to burn a blu-ray from an .ISO

Tags: blu-ray

In using `growisofs` to burn a blank Blu-Ray disk from an .ISO file I encounter the following error.

> /dev/dvdrw: media is not recognized as recordable DVD

How do I resolve this problem?

The command I used was:

> growisofs -speed=2 -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvdrw=/home/user/image.iso

This command was taken from this page, in the Blu-Ray part of the documentation:

[ubunutu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning)

Note that Nautilus shows the blank Blu-Ray just before I issue the `growisofs` command so I think I can assume Ubuntu is recognizing the device and disk medium. The screenshot shows the blank Blu-Ray in the upper left near the word "Device".
[image: Nautilus Screenshot]

The machine is the Samsung RF711.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10040 is much too large for a MMC profile number.
... diving into growisofs.c and growisofs_mmc.cpp ...

This is a synthetic code made up by growisofs.
Obviously it means "blank BD-ROM", which is quite a
strange state.

Only plausible theory for now:
The drive can only read but not write BD media.
A "combo drive". The Samsung RF711 laptop is advertised
with "DVD super multi" drive or "blu-ray playback".
chip.de reports about a "Blu-ray-Combo" drive.

The drive manufacturer and model name should be told

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/dvdrw 2>&1 | fgrep INQUIRY
```

Like

```
INQUIRY:            [HL-DT-ST][BD-RE  BH16NS40 ][1.00]
```

The following command should tell the list of supported
profiles:

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/dvdrw extra 2>&1 | fgrep -A 8  'GET [CUR'
```

A BD burner would report profiles 43, 42, 41, 40. Like

```
0000:  00 43 01 00 00 42 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 40 00 00
```

A BD combo would only report 40. Like

```
0000:  00 40 01 00 00 2b 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00 1a 00 00
```

Comment: It turns out you can discover that this a read only Blu-Ray device using K3b. In K3b click `Settings > Configure K3b > Devices` and look under the lists of "Read Capabilities" and "Write Capabilities".

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't there a hexadicimal number at the end of the message ?

growisofs emits this message if the MMC media profile reported by
the drive is not in its list of supported profiles.
The full message is supposed to be something like i get if i try
to burn to the empty drive /dev/sr0:

```
:-( /dev/sr0: media is not recognized as recordable DVD: 0
```

Among the supported profiles are "41" BD-R, "42" BD-R POW, "43" BD-RE.
So the text about "DVD" is outdated.

Your BD medium is recognized by Nautilus, which probably relies
on udev, which got the info from the kernel, which looks for the
MMC profile number, too.
So probably "/dev/dvdrw" is simply not the drive with the medium.

What happens if you use "/dev/sr0" instead ?

What happens if you do:  eject /dev/dvdrw
Does any drive tray come out anywhere ?

If you can affort to install xorriso, then you may get an overview
of drive addresses by doing as superuser

```
xorriso -devices
```

Comment: The complete message is /dev/dvdrw: media is not recognized as recordable DVD: 10040

Comment: Yes, eject /dev/dvdrw does eject the tray.

Comment: Use of /dev/sr0 results in the same code: /dev/sr0: media is not recognized as recordable DVD: 10040